# 急にphpmyadminが使えなくなりました。

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin

急にphpmyadminが使えなくなりました。

出来なくなる前に、laravelのプロジェクトファイルの.envにパスワードの設定をしただけです。
それが原因で接続できなくなったとは考えにくいです。
リセットして再度使えるようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: phpmyadminの設定とlaravelの設定で違いはありますか？またそれぞれの設定でコンソールからデータベースにつなごうとするとどうなりますか？

Comment: mysql 自体には接続出来てdbも壊れていません。

Comment: phpmyadminの設定とlaravelの設定で違いはないということですね。さらにその設定でコンソールからはつなげるということですね。ではphpmyadminはDBと同じサーバに設定されていますか？

Comment: はい、同じサーバに設定をしています。